# box-shadow and backgrounds

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on the following css code

```
.Console{ 
    background: blue;
    display: block;      
    box-shadow:  0px 12px 15px -2px #692;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 200px;            
    height: 50px;
}
```

What I want is to add a specific color to each corner of the background. Is that possible?

Comment: If you don't mind adding 4 different divs, yes. CSS doesn't have any background properties that will specifically color only the corners.

Comment: i actually dont mind. you mean i´d nest them into each other? How would that be done though, having a hard time seeing the structure.

Comment: Yea I'm with **Andy**, can you post an image example?

Comment: I cant post an example, but I posted the code? If you picture each corner in a new color thats what i´m trying to obtain.

Comment: basically you have a trimmed rectangle with four corners, each corner needs its own inset color

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment which is not very clear...

> *basically you have a trimmed rectangle with four corners, each corner needs its own inset color*

You can just use `border`:

```
#el { border-width: 5px; border-color: red blue green orange; }
```

You can also add multiple `box-shadow`:

```
#el { box-shadow: 1px 1px red, 1px 1px green, 1px 1px blue; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following css properties

border-top-color,border-left-color-border-right-color,border-bottom-color

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
border-width: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
```

you can adjust this line to modify your border pattern. try values from 0px onwards for each sides. It will change the shape of border sides which will create good styles beyond your imagination.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">

.sssssss{
background-color:#FFFF33;/*yellow*/
line-height:10px;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
border-style: solid; 
border-width: 30px 30px 30px 30px; 
border-right-color: #FF0000;/*red*/
border-bottom-color: #000;/*black*/
border-top-color: #00F;/*blue*/
border-left-color: #0F6; /*green*/
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div  class="sssssss">erulerjgnio;jerglerg</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

```
border-width: 70px 20px 0 20px; /* Play around with 1st and 4th value to change slant degree */
border-right-color: #DBDFEC;
border-bottom-color: transparent;
border-top-color: transparent;
border-left-color: transparent;
```

This modification made the result as below

[image]

Comment: For that last example #DBDFEC is given as page background as well as my right side border color